# VBA Excel Label Generator, Adding a number for each type of label

Tags: excel, label, vba

Morning guys.

I made a Label Generator in Excel, on which I converted the items chosen in dropdown lists to leters which translate to these items chosen.

This convertion is quite simple.

```
If tipoChosen = "UTP" Then
tipo = "U"
End If
```

This happens for every user input about the label.

I also had to add a number that made each label different, so I made this line:

```
FinalLabel = tipo & forn & Format(Nextrow - 2, "00000") & "." & Color & "(" & metragem & ")"
```

Where the "Format(Nextrow - 2, "00000")" Would give me a number depending on which row it was, beggining in 00000 and going through infinity and beyond(until long capacity ended). This worked and I was happy with it.

My boss just told me that what I did was wrong, and that it needs to reset this number for each type of cable. Meaning that

> if all the other parameters stay the same, it keeps counting.
>
> If it changes it goes back to 00000
>
> If it goes back to whatever type I already used, it keeps counting from the previous number.

And I honestly have no clue on how to do this the way I made my code. Will I need to do it from scratch and work my way around this? Or is there a way to implement this feature as it is?

Edit: I also have numerical inputs, things such as the lenght of the cable, thing that will change the label. Meaning that there needs to be a "check" to see if that lenght was also used before. Remember that:

> if ALL parameters are identical, keep counting from 00000 to whatever labels are to create. (let's say 00100)
>
> if something changes it starts from 00000
>
> if it goes back to a previous used combination of parameters it KEEPS counting from whatever number it was previously. (meaning the next one would be 00101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely rework what you have already.

You'll need to add a counter variable for each type, to keep track of the count. Set these counters to 0 at the start of your code.

Easiest method: `Dim` an array with an element for each type, which will contain the counter for that type:

```
Dim i
Dim Counter(1 To 5) As Integer
For i = 1 to 5
   Counter(i).Value = 0
Next i
```

Each time you change your type, update the `counter` index (`i`). You could use a select statement here to set `tipo` & `Counter` index (`i`):

```
Select Case tipoChosen
Case "UTP"
  tipo = "U"
  i = 1
Case "otherType"
  tipo = "X"
  i = 2
// etc...
End Select
```

Then increment `Counter` for each iteration, until the type changes.

```
FinalLabel = tipo & forn & Format(Counter(i).value, "00000") & "." & 
   Color & "(" & metragem & ")"
Counter(i).value = Counter(i).value + 1
```

There are better ways to do this, but this is probably the easiest solution. If you want the more complex approach, go with dynamic variable names, or using a pointer from main counter to type counter but that’s more complicated….

Comment: Thank you for your help,
However wouldn't this only work if the "tipoChosen" changes?

Maybe I wasn't so clear in my question, as you can see in the FinalLabel output I have various "types" I have :
> tipoChosen
> colorChosen
> metragemChosen
> fornChosen
Would I need to do as many counters as my "types" ?

Comment: That's why I put the `Select Case tipoChosen` in. Perhaps you could adapt it more to your needs? Or update the question to make it clearer what you are asking for?

Comment: You're right and I now understood how to implementate these counters. However I believe I'm expliciting my needs in my question as you can see when I say that " if ALL the OTHER parameters stay the same, it keeps counting." Not only "tipoChosen".

Comment: Plus I have numerical inputs, i.e. how much is the cable lenght, information that would change the label, meaning this solution of "Cases" won't help since it wouldn't be rational to be coding every single input a user could imagine and checking if he used it before.